# Get a list of objects from DB, create a ViewModel and populate its property by single LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list of collections of books in my database. I would like to get these collections by a query, create a ViewModel and populate its `List` property with them.

At this moment my code looks like this:

```
var collectionList = db.BookCollections.ToList();

var bookCreateViewModel = new BookCreateViewModel()
{
    Collection = collectionList
};
```

The ViewModel has a property:

```
public class BookCreateViewModel
{
    public List<BookCollection> Collection { get; set; }

    ///rest of the code
}
```

Is this possible to be done by a single LINQ statement?
Thank you!

Comment: You don't require LINQ for this, actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in one statement, then assign the result of your query in the initializer:

```
var bookCreateViewModel = new BookCreateViewModel()
{
    Collection =  db.BookCollections.ToList()
};
```

Comment: Assuming that the ViewModel and database model are the same object structure. Otherwise he would need to add projection into the single line assignment,

Comment: Well, I'm assuming that according to what he shows in the first piece of code ;)

Comment: The ViewModel's Collection property and database `BookCollection` are of the same type. Thank you @octavioccl. I am so fascinated by LINQ and lambda statements that I actually want to use it as often as possible. Sometimes too often, it seems.

Comment: lol, yeap, but remember Linq was created to consult data ;). Happy coding.